# What is the US Supreme Court case with the highest number of US states party to the case?

Tags: united-states, supreme-court

Sometimes US Supreme Court cases have had more than one US state as a party, e.g. in [*Massachusetts v. EPA*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massachusetts_v._Environmental_Protection_Agency)

> The petitioners were the states of California, Connecticut, Illinois, Maine, Massachusetts, New Jersey, New Mexico, New York, Oregon, Rhode Island, Vermont and Washington [plus some cities, organizations, and Washington DC].

I've counted 12 states there, not including DC. Also

> Respondents were the Environmental Protection Agency, [...] and the states of Michigan, Alaska, Idaho, Kansas, Nebraska, North Dakota, Ohio, South Dakota, Texas, and Utah.

That seems to be 10 states on the opposing side, so 22 states were party to the case on one side or the other.

Basically, I'm trying to find out if there are there US Supreme Court cases (that were granted certiorari) and that had a higher number of US states as parties. So, what's the Supreme Court case with the highest number of US states parties to it (not necessarily all on the same side)?

To make this question a little more interesting and answerable, if *Massachusetts v. EPA* turns out to be the case with the highest state count among the parties, what's the case with the 2nd highest such count?

Comment: It hasn't reached the Supreme Court yet, but the recent [recent antitrust suit against Facebook](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/facebook-antitrust-lawsuit-ftc-46-states-instagram-whatsapp/) included 46 states + DC and Guam.

Comment: @divibisan: I don't see mentioned in there why it might reach SCOTUS.

Comment: @Fizz If Facebook loses and gets ordered to sell off assets, it's pretty much a 337% guarantee it'll get to SCOTUS, because no way in a frozen-over hell inside another frozen-over hell would Facebook ever do that without exhausting every legal recourse.  Of course that's still hypothetical, but a "might reach" scenario is clearly easily conceived.

Comment: @Sjoerd: those are not all requests to join as a party, some are amicus briefs.

Comment: @Fizz Ah, I didn't pick up on that you wanted to make that distinction. But yes, if you don't count amici, my comments are invalid.

Comment: @Sjoerd: well, not entirely, I mean about half the states are arguing that the other half don't have standing to sue. If the case gets accepted they might decide to join, although I'm not sure if that's technically possible after certiorari. The reason I asked the q like this (about parties) is that it can be hard[er] to find out who submitted amicus briefs.

Comment: Interesting. I have no idea. The data set is pretty small, about a dozen or so a year or less, so it wouldn't be impossible to determine by brute force.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy the supreme court agrees to hear a very small percentage of the cases that it is asked to hear.  Of course Facebook would appeal to the supreme court if they lose, but that doesn't mean that the supreme court is likely to hear the case.

Answer (score 7):

If you include amici curiae, [46 states](https://www.kff.org/health-reform/issue-brief/explaining-california-v-texas-a-guide-to-the-case-challenging-the-aca/) (and D.C.) were involved at some point in *California v. Texas*, which was argued before the Court in November. 40 states (and D.C.) were *parties* to the case at some point or time.

**Eighteen states are suing to have the Affordable Care Act struck down entirely**: Texas, Arizona, Utah, North Dakota, South Dakota, Kansas, Nebraska, Indiana, West Virginia, Louisiana, Arkansas, Missouri, Tennessee, Mississippi, Alabama, Georgia, South Carolina, Florida

**Two states originally sued, but withdrew from the case when their Republican governors lost election and became amici curiae for the defense**: Wisconsin, Maine

**Sixteen states (and D.C.) successfully petitioned to defend the ACA in court**: California, Washington, Oregon, Minnesota, Illinois, Kentucky, Virginia, Hawaii, North Carolina, New York, Vermont, Massachusetts, Rhode Island, Connecticut, New Jersey, Delaware, D.C.

**Four states later joined the ACA defense**: Iowa, Nevada, Colorado, Michigan

**Four states were never parties and are amici curiae in the ACA's defense**: New Hampshire, Pennsylvania, Maryland, New Mexico

**Two states are amici curiae on neither parties' behalf**: Montana, Ohio

The only four states who haven't staked out some sort of position are Alaska, Idaho, Wyoming, and Oklahoma. Not sure if this the record, but it's at least a contender.